# I install my package but I don't know how respond to "Proceed ([y]/n)? " in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda, anaconda3

I would install qpcr package with Jupyter notebook. I set my script in the following manner, but I don't know proceed after this question "Proceed ([y]/n)?". I tried to put "--yes" or "-y" after the name-package but the result was the same.

conda update conda

!conda install  qpcr

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/nsefora/anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - conda


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    navigator-updater-0.4.0    |  py310hca03da5_0         2.3 MB
    nspr-4.35                  |       h313beb8_0         243 KB
    nss-3.89.1                 |       h313beb8_0         1.8 MB
    r-diagram-1.6.5            |    r41ha770c72_1         679 KB  conda-forge
    r-future-1.32.0            |    r41hc72bb7e_0         606 KB  conda-forge
    r-future.apply-1.11.0      |    r41hc72bb7e_0         161 KB  conda-forge
    r-globals-0.16.2           |    r41hc72bb7e_0         117 KB  conda-forge
    r-jsonlite-1.8.5           |    r41h21dc0da_0         617 KB  conda-forge
    r-lava-1.7.2.1             |    r41hc72bb7e_0         2.3 MB  conda-forge
    r-listenv-0.9.0            |    r41hc72bb7e_0         118 KB  conda-forge
    r-parallelly-1.36.0        |    r41hc72bb7e_0         355 KB  conda-forge
    r-prodlim-2023.03.31       |    r41h9a38a31_0         421 KB  conda-forge
    r-progressr-0.13.0         |    r41hc72bb7e_0         342 KB  conda-forge
    r-shape-1.4.6              |    r41ha770c72_1         796 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        10.8 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  r-diagram          conda-forge/noarch::r-diagram-1.6.5-r41ha770c72_1 
  r-future           conda-forge/noarch::r-future-1.32.0-r41hc72bb7e_0 
  r-future.apply     conda-forge/noarch::r-future.apply-1.11.0-r41hc72bb7e_0 
  r-globals          conda-forge/noarch::r-globals-0.16.2-r41hc72bb7e_0 
  r-listenv          conda-forge/noarch::r-listenv-0.9.0-r41hc72bb7e_0 
  r-parallelly       conda-forge/noarch::r-parallelly-1.36.0-r41hc72bb7e_0 
  r-progressr        conda-forge/noarch::r-progressr-0.13.0-r41hc72bb7e_0 
  r-shape            conda-forge/noarch::r-shape-1.4.6-r41ha770c72_1 

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  navigator-updater                   0.3.0-py310hca03da5_0 --> 0.4.0-py310hca03da5_0 
  nspr                                      4.33-hc377ac9_0 --> 4.35-h313beb8_0 
  nss                                       3.74-h142855e_0 --> 3.89.1-h313beb8_0 
  r-jsonlite                            1.8.4-r41h5d63f41_0 --> 1.8.5-r41h21dc0da_0 
  r-lava                                1.6.9-r41hc72bb7e_0 --> 1.7.2.1-r41hc72bb7e_0 
  r-prodlim                        2019.11.13-r41h9a38a31_2 --> 2023.03.31-r41h9a38a31_0 

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  ca-certificates    conda-forge::ca-certificates-2023.5.7~ --> pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2023.01.10-hca03da5_0 
  certifi            conda-forge/noarch::certifi-2023.5.7-~ --> pkgs/main/osx-arm64::certifi-2023.5.7-py310hca03da5_0 
  openssl            conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1u-h53f4e23_0 --> pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1t-h1a28f6b_0 


Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

I tried:

!conda update conda

!conda install  qpcr --yes

but I don't resolve the problem

Comment: have you tried to put `!conda install --yes qpcr` or alternatively just running this command from your normal terminal?